# Spring Cloud API Gateway Whitelabel Error Page after page reload

Tags: api-gateway, spring-cloud-gateway

I have my Spring Cloud API Gateway Setup to forward requests on / to my angular frontend. And this works, until I reload the page. Then I get the empty Spring 404 Page, or I get an error 431 header is too big. I already increased the headear size to 2MB, which is way to much but this does not solve the issue.

I also tried adding a seperate catch all route but with no help
When I enable the logs what I can see is that i get many redirects. Like 20 in a row.

```
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: jango-board-backend
          uri: ${jango_BOARD_BE_URL:http://localhost:8081}/api/project
          predicates:
            - Path=/api/project/**
        - id: project-overview
          uri: ${jango_BOARD_FE_URL:http://localhost:4200}/project/overview
          predicates:
            - Path=/project/overview
        - id: jango-board-frontend
          uri: ${jango_BOARD_FE_URL:http://localhost:4200}
          # The gateway will redirect requests from / (after login with azure ad, azure redirects the user back to
          # the api gateway) to the jango-board-frontend
          predicates:
            - Path=/,/*.css,/*.js,/favicon.ico
#        - id: catch-all
#          uri: ${jango_BOARD_FE_URL:http://localhost:4200/}
#          predicates:
#            - Path=/**
```